# Sharepoint 2010 CAML QUERY Can't find file

Tags: development, caml-query

I'm wanting to check a document out from an SP site, but my code/CAMLQuery can't find it (it's defo there). It stops at the ExecuteNonQuery line, saying it can't find the FileIWantToGet.xlsx I've not done any SP work before nor heard of CAMLQuery until this bit of work.

I have asked this on StackOverFlow but can't move it to here.

Any help appreciated.

```
using System;
```

using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2013.Excel;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
// The following using directive resolves the ambiguity
// between the System.IO.File class and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File
// class.
using ClientOM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static private void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream destination)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead != 0);
    }

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASS", "WINAD");
    string SPSite = "https://www.COMPANYPORTAL.COM";
    string DirStruc = "/sp/CorporateITPro/BusinessDocuments/Migration/Templates/Master";       
    string dFile = "MigClassification.xslx";

    ClientContext clientContext;
    clientContext = new ClientContext(SPSite);
    clientContext.Credentials = cred;

    Web spWebsite;
    spWebsite = clientContext.Web;

    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(dFile);        
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml =("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>");
    camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = DirStruc;

    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
        item => item.File.Name,
        item => item.File.Author,
        item => item.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
        item => item["Proposalx0020Navigationx0020Grouping"],
        item => item["Modified"])
        );

    try
    {
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();// NOT FOUND ERROR HERE
        if (listItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                item.File.CheckOut();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // GET SOME DATA RELATED TO THE FILE FROM A DB
                // PUT DATA IN THE FILE

                item.File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }        
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When you want to search a file by its name, you should use the 'FileLeafRef' as the FieldRef in your CamlQuery, because 'FileDirRef' basically points to the directory.

So, your camlQuery should look like:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                          <Query>
                              <Where>
                                  <BeginsWith>
                                      <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>
                                      <Value Type='Text'>/subdir0/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/" + dFile + @"</Value>
                                  </BeginsWith>
                              </Where>
                          </Query>
                     </View>";
```

Comment: Hi, @Andy thanks for that but it still can't find the file. Is this code correct
'code' List list = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(dFile);        
As it erros that it "can't find the List"

Comment: (pressed Enter by mistake there...)

when this line execs    `code` _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: When "can't find the List" error occurred, it means that you've used wrong list name. For example, in those line:

List list = _spWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle(dFile);

you passed fileName as list name, and of course it won't find the list (except the list and the file have the same name).

Please make sure you have proper list name based on the list in your SharePoint site.

Comment: I wonder then if I'm doing this right. It seems to Find the Calendar (or at least doesn't error). but the File (an xlsx) can be found. Do I need to look for a file instead?

Comment: .."Can't be found "that was meant to say.

Comment: please post your updated code instead, and if possible please post another information related to this question, like the location of the file and the list name.

Comment: Hi @Andy, i've updated the code in the original post. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please check the List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(dFile); line, because from what I saw there, you are still using the filename to get a List. Please refer to your List name in your SharePoint site.

Comment: Thanks, i missed a hyphen out of the name!!! So I've managed to move it on to a different error, "Value does not fall within the expected range." Again on the first ExecuteQuery() lline

Comment: Seems like you have tried to fetch data from nonexistent field, for example, please check this line: item["Proposalx0020Navigationx0020Grouping"]. When you want to get value from field with spaces, you should replace the space with _x0020_ like: item["Proposal_x0020_Navigation_x0020_Grouping"].ToString()

Comment: I commented all that block out but it gives the same error. I might just give this up.